# How to wait until context value is set?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to render a header.

First, in InnerList.js, I make an API call, and with the data from the API call, I set a list in context.

Second, in Context.js, I take the list and set it to a specific data.

Then, in InnerListHeader.js, I use the specific data to render within the header.

**Problem:** I currently get a TypeError undefined because the context is not set before rendering. Is there a way to wait via async or something else for the data to set before loading?

My code block is below. I've been looking through a lot of questions on StackOverflow and blogs but to no avail. Thank you!

InnerList.js

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dtc_id } = this.props.match.params;

    const {
      setSpecificDtcCommentList,
    } = this.context;

    MechApiService.getSpecificDtcCommentList(dtc_id)
      .then(res => 
        setSpecificDtcCommentList(res)
      )
  }

  renderSpecificDtcCommentListHeader() {
    const { specificDtc = [] } = this.context;
    return (
      <InnerDtcCommentListItemHeader key={specificDtc.id} specificDtc={specificDtc} />
      )
  }
```

Context.js

```
  setSpecificDtcCommentList = (specificDtcCommentList) => {
    this.setState({ specificDtcCommentList })
    this.setSpecificDtc(specificDtcCommentList)
  }

  setSpecificDtc = (specificDtcCommentList) => {
    this.setState({ specificDtc: specificDtcCommentList[0] })
  }
```

InnerListHeader.js

```
  render() {
    const { specificDtc } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="InnerDtcCommentListItemHeader__comment">
          {specificDtc.dtc_id.dtc}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should always consider that a variable can reach the rendering stage without a proper value (e.g. unset). It is up to you prevent a crash on that.

For instance, you could rewrite you snippet as follows:

```
  render() {
    const { specificDtc } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="InnerDtcCommentListItemHeader__comment">
          {Boolean(specificDtc.dtc_id) && specificDtc.dtc_id.dtc}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in all scenarios. Is there an alternative way to solve this same issue?

Comment: which scenario do you mean? the goal is either have a function able to evaluate its value without errors, or short-circuit it and return false, which instruct React to render nothing.

Comment: It seems it takes time for the context to set. Sometimes the context is empty (undefined), and sometimes it's not. The conditional operator in the solution above works in the particular example mentioned in the original post. The conditional operator doesn't work in other scenarios that require a set context. I have a codebase that looks almost identical to the one mentioned here, but it doesn't work in that case.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/peyo/fd9c58d7f644cab7ca37e650f86dfc63 See this gist for the full example.

It looks like `renderFilteredDtcCommentListHeader()` renders before `componentDidMount()` and causes the undefined TypeError.

Is there a way to delay the `renderFiltered...` until the componentDidMount() fully runs?

Comment: @peyo the componentDidMount method is called **after** the first rendering: it's by design. What you need is to perform the actual rendering only when all of the fundamental variables are correctly loaded. I think you should consider an approach like the other answer, then. A flag is set only when everything is okay, and before that the component will render something like a "wait indication".

Comment: As personal suggestion, I invite you to consider the functional approach of React, then the class based. It is a bit hard at the beginning, especially if you use to deal with classes. However, as soon you catch the essence, you'll understand **way** better how the framework work, and your code will be **way** more compact yet cleaner. Have a look here: https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214303/discussion-between-peyo-and-mario-vernari).

Answer (score 2):

When you make an api call you can set a loader while the data is being fetched from the api and once it is there you show the component that will render that data.
In your example you can add a new state that will pass the api call status to the children like that

```
render() {
    const { specificDtc, fetchingData  } = this.props;
     if (fetchingData){
      return <p>Loading</p>
     }else{
     return (
      <div>
        <div className="InnerDtcCommentListItemHeader__comment">
          {specificDtc.dtc_id.dtc}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
    }
``
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i am calling external api to firebase which lead to that context pass undefined for some values like user. so i have used loading set to wait untile the api request is finished and then return the provider

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    signOut,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    GoogleAuthProvider,
    signInWithPopup,
    updateProfile
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { create_user_db, get_user_db } from 'api/UserAPI';
import { CircularProgress, LinearProgress } from '@mui/material';
import Loader from 'ui-component/Loader';

const UserContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const [user_db, setUserDB] = useState();
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const createUser = async (email, password) => {
        const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    };

    const signIn = (email, password) => {
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then(() => setIsAuthenticated(true))
            .catch(() => setIsAuthenticated(false));
    };

    const googleSignIn = async () => {
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
            .then(() => setIsAuthenticated(true))
            .catch(() => setIsAuthenticated(false));
    };

    const logout = () => {
        setUser();
        return signOut(auth).then(() => {
            window.location = '/login';
        });
    };

    const updateUserProfile = async (obj) => {
        await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, obj);
        return updateUser(obj);
    };

    const updateUser = async (user) => {
        return setUser((prevState) => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                ...user
            };
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (currentUser) => {
            setLoading(true);
            if (currentUser) {
                const user_db = await get_user_db({ access_token: currentUser.accessToken });
                setUserDB(user_db);
                setUser(currentUser);
                setIsAuthenticated(true);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        });
        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        };
    }, []);

    if (loading) return <Loader />;

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ createUser, user, user_db, isAuthenticated, logout, signIn, googleSignIn, updateUserProfile }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const UserAuth = () => {
    return useContext(UserContext);
};
```